# ASP.Net Change ImageButton.ImageUrl on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, asp.net, imagebutton

I am learning ASP.Net. I have a dynamically created ImageButton that I would like to change the ImageURL for when the user hovers over the control. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
 imgStars.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src= '~/Images/4Stars.png'")
```

If I set the imgStars.ImageURL in the codebehind to ~/Images/4Stars.png it works. But it does not work in javascript.

Please help. I have tried searching for my answer for hours, but I do not have a clue what to do.

Comment: The tilde "~" is a special character used in path resolution on the *server.  This kind of path will not work on the client (which is where the script will run).  You'll need to render a path that the browser understands.

Comment: That did the trick. I hate it when the answer is so simple. I changed '~/Images/4Stars.png' to 'Images/4Stars.png' and it worked. I am not sure how to mark your comment as the answer. If you do let me know. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"xanadont" answered you right but your solution will not work for every scenario.  To ensure that every relative directory will be usable by the client, use this code snippet:

```
imgStars.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src= '" + this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/4Stars.png") + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but I get an error on "this" it says that it is undefined. I am coding in VB instead of C#. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it's a syntax difference.  Use "Me" instead of "this"

Answer (score 0):

in VB you should use the following code:

```
    *imgBtnRegister.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Register_2.jpg") + "'")
        imgBtnRegister.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Register_1.jpg") + "'")*

use *Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Register_2.jpg")* instead of *this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/Register_2.jpg")*
```